# Reflection code gets error in .NetStandard or .NetFramework

Tags: c#, reflection, html-agility-pack

I have forked [HtmlAgilityPack](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack) to my github and clone it to my visual studio.

[image: The project]

The HtmlAgilityPack targets **.NetFramework 2.0** and HtmlAgilityPack.NetStandard targets **.NetStandard 1.6**

I added some reflection codes to **HtmlAgilityPack.Shared** , for example :

```
public static PropertyInfo GetFirstPropertyInfo(Type t)
{       
     return t.GetProperties().First();
}
```

It gets me this error :

> 'Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetProperties' and no
>   extension method 'GetProperties' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)  **HtmlAgilityPack.NETStandard**

After some StackOverflowing I found out I should use this code instead :

```
public static PropertyInfo GetFirstPropertyInfo(Type t)
{       
     return t.GetTypeInfo().GetProperties().First();
}
```

but this code gets error in .NetFramework !

> 'Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetTypeInfo' and no
>   extension method 'GetTypeInfo' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)  **HtmlAgilityPack**

What should I do ???

Thanks.

Comment: Did you import the System.Reflection namespace?

Comment: @Eric yes I did.